# tr replaced space with newline not giving unique values in with uniq

Tags: unix, tr, uniq

i am tring to replace space characters with newline characters using tr and then passing the output to uniq for displaying unique values but i'm not getting the output that i'm expecting.what's the reason only the word "world" is not displayed since it's unique?

```
echo "hello world hello" | tr ' ' '\n' | uniq -u
```

Answer (score 1):

The `uniq` filter will only remove duplicates if they are *consecutive*. The manpage is quite explicit about that (my emphasis):

> Filter ***adjacent*** matching lines from INPUT (or standard input), writing to OUTPUT (or standard output).

That means you almost certainly want to sort the data before passing it into `uniq`:

```
pax> echo "hello world hello" | tr ' ' '\n' | uniq -u
hello
world
hello

pax> echo "hello world hello" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq -u
world
```